# $inc not working in mongodb in case array Like qty in stock

Tags: mongodb

**Que:Increment the quantity by 10, for item_id "IJK2"**

```
{
    item: "IJK2",
    details: { model: "14Q2", manufacturer: "M5 Corporation" },
    stock: [ { size: "S", qty: 5 }, { size: "L", qty: 1 } ],
    category: "houseware"
}
```

> My query is but i am getting an error

```
db.inventory.update({item:IJK2},{$inc:{stock.qty:10}})
```

Answer (score 0):

In mongo 3.6 you can use the [positional-all](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/) operator:

```
db.test.updateOne(
    {
        item: 'IJK2'
    },
    {
        $inc: {
            'stock.$[].qty': 10
        }
    }
)
```

Comment: Still error is coming

Comment: @Gauravverma what is the error?